# How do I fit these queries into just one?

Tags: mysql, if-statement

Okay, I'm going to try it again... this time I definitely got it right. Sorry about the confusion. :(

**table1**:

```
+----+---------+------------+------+
| id | item_id | product_id | type |
+----+---------+------------+------+
```

**table2, table3, table4**:

```
+----+---------+
| id | item_id |
+----+---------+
```

Here is my **main query**:

```
$sql = "SELECT t1.* FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2 WHERE t2.id = '1' AND 
t2.item_id = t1.item_id AND t1.type NOT IN ('type1', 'type2') LIMIT 5";

$a = mysql_query($sql);
while($b = mysql_fetch_assoc($a))
```

And now I want to integrate **these 2 queries**:

**1st query**:

AND IF `t1.type = 'type3'` THEN

```
SELECT t3.item_id FROM table3 AS t3 WHERE t3.id = t1.product_id AND
t3.item_id NOT IN (SELECT t2.item_id FROM table2 AS t2 WHERE t2.id = '1')
```

ONLY if this statement `t3.item_id NOT IN (...)` in the above query is true, then `t1.id` from the **main query** should be displayed. However, if `t3.item_id is IN (...)` then it should be excluded from the results.

**2nd query**:

AND IF `t1.type = 'type4'` THEN

```
SELECT t4.item_id FROM table4 AS t4 WHERE t4.id = t1.product_id AND
t4.item_id NOT IN (SELECT t2.item_id FROM table2 AS t2 WHERE t2.id = '1')
```

Same as with the **1st query**.

Does this all fit into one query? I'd need it in one query only, so I know which results to show on the next page, e.g. `LIMIT 5,5`

Comment: It's not very clear but I think you can use the `EXISTS` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly but I think `(NOT) EXISTS` should be used:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table1 AS t1
  JOIN table2 AS t2 
    ON t2.item_id = t1.item_id
WHERE t2.id = '1' 
  AND t1.type NOT IN ('type1', 'type2')
  AND NOT ( t1.type = 'type3' 
            AND EXISTS 
                ( SELECT t3.item_id
                  FROM table3 AS t3
                  WHERE t3.id = t1.product_id
                    AND t3.item_id NOT IN
                          ( SELECT t2.item_id 
                            FROM table2 AS t2
                            WHERE t2.id = '1' )
                )
           ) 
  AND NOT ( t1.type = 'type4' 
            AND EXISTS 
                ( SELECT t4.item_id
                  FROM table4 AS t4
                  WHERE t4.id = t1.product_id
                    AND t4.item_id NOT IN
                          ( SELECT t2.item_id 
                            FROM table2 AS t2
                            WHERE t2.id = '1' )
                )
           ) 
ORDER BY WhatYouWant
LIMIT x,y
```

Answer (score 0):

apply the [`flow control flow structure`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) in mysql

```
CASE case_value
    WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
    [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

Or:

```
CASE
    WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list
    [WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```